# Incomprehensible "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null" error

Tags: vue.js

In my app, clicking a certain button changes its caption to a different one, and clicking it again changes it back to the default caption.

When clicking it I get this error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null

This doesn't make sense to me because there's no DOM manipulation here. I simplified my code as much as possible while keeping the error:

```
data () {
  return {
    ctaCaptions: [
      'see case studies',
      'hide case studies'
    ],
    ctaCaption: ''
  }
},
methods: {
  handleClick () {
    this.ctaCaption = this.ctaCaptions[1]
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<a
  @click="handleClick"
  v-html="ctaCaption"
/>
```

Any suggestion as to what causes this error?

Answer (score 1):

```
methods: {
  handleClick () {
    this.ctaCaption = this.ctaCaptions[1]
  }
}
```

Inside event handlers, `this` points to the `event.target` (in your case the `HTMLButtonElement`).

In your case, you want a reference to your component. You can achieve this in different ways:

Use explicit binding:

```
methods: {
  handleClick () {
    this.ctaCaption = this.ctaCaptions[1]
  }.bind(this)
}
```

Or you can use an ES6 arrow function (these preserve the `this` at the moment of definition rather than at execution time):

```
methods: {
  handleClick: () => {
    this.ctaCaption = this.ctaCaptions[1]
  }
}
```

For a more specific and precise insight, you'd have to show the HTML snippet which uses the model code you've shown. Also, no line in your showcased code uses `removeChild`.

Comment: When adding `=>` to make `handleClick` an arrow function I'm getting `Syntax Error: Unexpected token, expected "{"` error. Also I edited the question to add HTML snippet. Finally indeed I don't use `removeChild` anywhere in my component's code (nor throughout my app actually), that's the most puzzling aspect of my problem.

Comment: I recommend not to use `v-html` for simple text. Instead, use `<a @click="handleClick">{{ctaCaption}}</a>`. Also, `a` cannot be self-closing (though not sure if that's allowed in Vue templates).

Comment: I did so and it made the `removeChild` problem disappear somehow... Thanks! Not sure what to do in terms of accepting answers here though?